# Pycharm Background color setting

Tags: pycharm

I just want to change editor background color of pycharm, but seems it provides a lot of different choices for different fields, it is really unnecessary, where can I change for just the whole background color, after looking for a while, I still not find it...
[image]

Comment: pycharm community edition comes with 6 preloaded color options for the terminal. Follow this, Editor->Color Scheme->Scheme, here in the given dropdown, select the desired color theme. In can see in the pic you posted that, you're at wrong tab. Change Schema from "Github" to desired one from the available options

Comment: you are right !

Answer (score 0):

Just for editor's background color.

You can try Editor->Color Scheme->Console Colors->(from right side frame)Console drawdown->(1st selection)Background.

right side again, select the Background item and change the value to 000000.